# UWP Multiple VisualState Triggers in VisualStateManager

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, win-universal-app, visualstatemanager

I'm creating a Windows Universal App

I want to do layout combined with 3 columns. Each column is showing different informations.

**First** column contains `ListView`. If you select an item, the **Second** column should show up.

**Second** column contains also `ListView`. If you select an item, the **Third** solumn should show up.

In **Third** column are shown some informations.

I need to show up only columns, that showing some informations (blank column hide). Also I want to add responsive feature. So on mobile should be shown only one column with the biggest priority.

**Here is an example**

Desktop (start):

|     1     |

Desktop (click on first ListView):

|  1  |  2  |

Desktop (click on the second ListView):

| 1 | 2 | 3 |

Mobile(start):

| 1 |

Desktop (click on first ListView):

| 2 |

Desktop (click on the second ListView):

| 3 |

So I want to create `VisualState` with two StateTriggers.

Something like this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="VSShowThird">
    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="750" />
        <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding Path=ShowThirdColumn}" />
    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="FirstColumn.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter Target="SecondColumn.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter Target="ThirdColumn.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="VSShowSecond">
    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="750" />
        <StateTrigger IsActive="{Binding Path=ShowSecondColumn}" />
    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="FirstColumn.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter Target="SecondColumn.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter Target="ThirdColumn.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
<VisualState x:Name="VSShowFirst">
    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="750" />
    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="FirstColumn.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        <Setter Target="SecondColumn.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        <Setter Target="ThirdColumn.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

But it isn't working properly.

Can You suggest me any solution for this?

Many thanks.

Comment: i achieve this im my app, extending the adaptive trager and adding a property is Active, but i'm having some problems wiht binding

Answer (score 0):

I create this trigger and me

```
public class AdaptiveTriggerWithState : AdaptiveTrigger
{
    private double _minWindowHeightProperty;
    private double _minWindowWidthProperty;
    private const int INACTIVE_STATE_SIZE = 10000;

    public static DependencyProperty IsActiveProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
                                "IsActive", 
                                typeof(bool), 
                                typeof(AdaptiveTriggerWithState), 
                                new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnIsActive_Changed));

    private static void OnIsActive_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var instance = (AdaptiveTriggerWithState)d;
        instance.IsActive = (bool)e.NewValue;
    }

    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsActiveProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsActiveProperty, value);
            SetValue(MinWindowHeightProperty, (IsActive ? this._minWindowHeightProperty : INACTIVE_STATE_SIZE));
            SetValue(MinWindowWidthProperty, (IsActive ? this._minWindowWidthProperty : INACTIVE_STATE_SIZE));
        }
    }

    public new System.Double MinWindowHeight
    {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(MinWindowHeightProperty); }
        set
        {
            this._minWindowHeightProperty = value;
            SetValue(MinWindowHeightProperty, (IsActive ? this._minWindowHeightProperty : INACTIVE_STATE_SIZE));
        }
    }
    public new System.Double MinWindowWidth
    {
        get { return (Double)GetValue(MinWindowWidthProperty); }
        set
        {
            this._minWindowWidthProperty = value;
            SetValue(MinWindowWidthProperty, (IsActive ? this._minWindowWidthProperty : INACTIVE_STATE_SIZE));
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: First thing, this doesn't really work, and second, you should post more elaborate comments, explaining what your code does and so on, not just copy-pasting a class with a single line of text that doesn't even has its grammar right.